# How can I list the paths of all (sub)folders and put them separately in a list?

Tags: python, list, path, operating-system, directory

I have a program that generates many folders and files inside of them. In the main folder, i want the Code to look for all folders inside of it and save them separately in a list. So with `self._list[0]` I want to get one folderpath.
I am new to Python but I know already some path-printing lines but none of this give me the path. With this code I get the name of the folders, but I need additionally the path:

```
self._folderList=os.listdir(self._mainFolderPath)
```

Comment: Please see [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

Answer (score 0):

you can attach the path manually to the folder name using this code:

```
self._folderList=[self._mainFolderPath + '\\' + folder_name for folder_name in os.listdir(self._mainFolderPath)]
```